# Poor signal strength from Unifi AP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

(Moved from Network Engineering Stack Exchange)

I recently bought a Unifi access point to switch my home network over to wireless, however my devices report low to average signal from the access point unless I'm less than 5 meters away.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. I moved the access point to various locations inside the house but this did not seem to make a difference.
2. I further ruled out interference by testing with two regular wi-fi routers (Netgear and Tenda) and do not seem to have the same issue with them.
3. I played around with the Channel and Tx power settings with no noticeable difference.

I figure it is most likely an issue with my access point settings rather than a faulty unit, so to debug the issue further I downloaded and ran NetSurveyor.  However, here I am out of my depth (I am a programmer, not a network administrator) and would like your help in solving the issue.

Here is the information I get from NetSurveyor:

- Chanel: 1
- Beacon Strength (dBm): -65
- Beacon Strength (mWatt x 10^6): 0.3162
- Beacon Quality: 44%
- Signal Quality: Very Good
- Radio Type: Unknown
- Encryption: YES
- Active: YES

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, an AP's radio settings should be perfectly fine for 99% of home installations. You have a defective AP.

Comment: I was starting to suspect as much, but was hoping to find I've missed something in the setup.  Thanks for the reply.